# Make a menu with fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want a menu that when the activity start, shows a fragment (MainFragment) with a list of options, when for example the first item in this list is clicked the MainFragment scroll to the left out of the screen and a new fragment (OptionOneFragment) scroll from the right in the screen. In the Options fragment will have a button on the top to go back to the MainFragment and another list of "sub options" related with the Main option menu that when any is clicked will open other activities.

The Relation of fragments is like:

```
MainFragment
     ListView
        Option1 - Slide out Main and Slide in 
                        -OptionOneFragment
                             <- BackButton (With a Slide Out)
                             ListView
                                Option1_1 = opens ActivityA
                                Option1_2 = opens ActivityB

        Option2 - Slide out Main and Slide in 
                        -OptionTwoFragment (With a Slide Out)
                             <- BackButton
                             ListView
                                Option2_1 = opens ActivityC
                                Option2_2 = opens ActivityD

        Option3 - Slide out Main and Slide in 
                        -OptionThreeFragment (With a Slide Out)
                             <- BackButton
                             ListView
                                Option3_1 = opens ActivityE
                                Option3_2 = opens ActivityF
```

What I have Right now is:

This is my activity_main layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".app.Activities.MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarMain">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my fragment_main layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".app.Activities.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/zxing_transparent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewMainMenu"
        android:background="#FFF"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

And my "fragment_option_one" layout. The other 2 are exactly the same

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".app.Activities.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/zxing_transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/back_button_dimen_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/back_button_dimen_height"
        android:id="@+id/buttomBackToMainMenu"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_backspace"
         />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewSubMenu"
        android:background="#FFF"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

My code is:

In MainActivity I have a initiator of the MainFragment

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Fragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, mainFragment, "MAIN_FRAGMENT");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
}
```

And in my MainFragment I call a function that changes the layout depending in the item clicked (Only in the Item 0, the other 2 I didn't make yet):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        thisFragment = this;
        manager= this.getFragmentManager();

        listViewMainMenu =(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMainMenu);

        menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        menuList.clear();

        menuList.add(0, "OptionOne");
        menuList.add(1, "OptionTwo");
        menuList.add(2, "OptionThree");

        menuAdapter = new MainMenuAdapter(getActivity(), menuList);

        listViewMainMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

        listViewMainMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case(0):
                        Shared.ShowFragment(manager, thisFragment, new OptionOneFragment(), 1);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

And in the OptionOneFragment I have almost the same thing:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_option_one, container, false);

        thisFragment = this;
        manager = this.getFragmentManager();

        buttomBackToMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.buttomBackToMenu);
        listViewSubMenu = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewSubMenu);

        menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        menuList.add(0,"Option1_1");
        menuList.add(1,"Option1_2");

        menuAdapter = new MainMenuAdapter(getActivity(),menuList);
        listViewSubMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

        buttomBackToMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Shared.ShowFragment(manager, thisFragment, new MainFragment(), 0);
            }
        });

        listViewSubMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case (0):
                        intent= new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class);
                        break;
                    case (1):
                        intent = null;
                        break;
                }
                if(intent!= null)
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

And my function Shared.ShowFragment that changes Fragment is (the animation works properly):

```
public static void ShowFragment(FragmentManager manager, Fragment thisFragment, Fragment destinyFragment, int customTransactionType) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        switch(customTransactionType){
            case (0):
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right);
                break;
            case (1):
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                break;
            default: break;
        }

        transaction.remove(thisFragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, destinyFragment);

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

I've seen this kind of menu I want before, but then when I tried to develop one I faced some issues, like if the app crashes for any reason it simply mess with all my layout. I'll explain it better with examples...

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered using a library to help you create a menu? I've tried out Mike Penz's Material Drawer library and it's really good for quickly setting up a menu.

There's plenty different preset styles you can choose from so I'm sure you could find something you like the look of.

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer